# Function named 'GetClipbox' cannot obtatin rectangle

Tags: c++, mfc

Recently, I attempt to obtain the rectangle by function `GetClipBox` in `OnDraw(CDC*pDC)`, having a glance at implements simply.

```
void CObjView::OnDraw(CDC* pDC)
{

    CRect expose;   

    int retVal = pDC->GetClipBox(&expose); 
}
```

As situation I expect, it works fine in almost time. But in several times, the object `expose` is empty, what it means is that the function `GetClipBox` isn't able to get rectangle. To make it correct, you can browse pictures in following section.

[image]
[image]

In picture one, There is a grid one created in parent window two. The object `expose` can be obtained accurately by `GetClipBox`. In picture two, Nonetheless, **the object `expose` is empty when grid is fully covered parent window**. Actually, the grid is zoom in bigger than parent window.
Hence, Can someone provide a scenario to solve this situation.

Best regards for everyone who can provide assistance to me.

Comment: if possible, i would love to try helping if you share your sample project with me. if you can zip sample and upload it..

Comment: @Hasan alattar Sorry, friend! I have not permission to share my project.

Comment: i ment sample of the problem not the project. so new project that contains this problem only

Comment: [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getclipbox): The GetClipBox function retrieves the dimensions of the tightest bounding rectangle that can be drawn around the **current visible area** on the device. The visible area is defined by the current clipping region or clip path, **as well as any overlapping windows**.

Comment: @Sergey Shevchenko Hey,should I then do anything to get still rectangle in my case

Comment: @Savner_Dig it depends on what you're goint to do. Try simply `GetClientRect`. Also you can try `pDC->GetBoundsRect` or `pDC->RectVisible` methods.

Comment: Actually,This grid can be bigger than parent window apperently in the way that zoom in it. Unfortunately, I can not zoom out this grid in this case, I cannot obtain expose. I   aim to get expose in order to zoom out this grid.

Comment: Ok, then show how zooming is implemented.